# Hidden features of the Lithium framework?

Tags: php, lithium

Since there isn't a lot of documentation out there, some features of the [**Lithium PHP Framework**](http://li3.me/) are not well known by the public. Are there any cool **code features** which I would miss if I just use the framework as shown in the [docs](http://rad-dev.org/lithium/wiki/about)?

Comment: These kinds of questions seem to stir up a lot of controversy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331399/hidden-features-of-go-closed

Comment: I'm interested in Lithium, but I'm waiting for it to mature a bit first.

Answer (score 3):

Hey, thanks for asking. Most of what you can do with Lithium currently is documented at http://li3.me/docs/lithium and http://dev.lithify.me/drafts/source. However, with each new release we usually write a blog post highlighting some of the features that have been added and what you can do with them. Those can be found here: http://dev.lithify.me/lithium/wiki/blog.

Let me know if you need anything else, or have any other questions. As always, feel free to drop by #li3 on Freenode.

Comment: Nate, it's been awhile since the last release. How are things progressing?

Comment: See here for a quick summary: http://dev.lithify.me/lithium/wiki/workshops-meetups-conferences -- Next week I'll have a "State of Lithium" post up on DevZone, which will give a more thorough overview of our status.

Answer (score 2):

Filters are a huge benefit in Lithium. Notice how one would do "beforeSave" and "afterSave":

http://www.patrickjsparrow.com/php/beforesave-and-aftersave-in-lithium/

Comment: Oh yeah very nice: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'lithium\action\DispatchException' with message 'Controller 'Php' not found' in /home........`

Comment: Sorry... I'm in the process of moving my coding blog to http://code.atavisticendeavor.com.  There is a post similar to the one missing from my site at http://amalraghav.com/lithium-filters-a-practical-example/.  It shows a good example of how to use filters in Lithium.